# what does the -1 mean in Scipy's voronoi algorithm?

Tags: python, graphics, scipy, computational-geometry, voronoi

I am trying to custom plot the [Voronoi](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) regions of random points in 2D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
pt = np.random.random((10,2))
x = sp.spatial.Voronoi(pt)

# trial an error to figure out the type structure of [x]

plt.plot(x.vertices[:,0], x.vertices[:,1], '.', markersize=5)

# how to iterate through the x.regions object?
for poly in x.regions:
    z = np.array([ x.vertices[k] for k in poly])
    print z
    if z.shape[0] > 0:
        plt.plot( z[:,0], z[:,1])

plt.xlim([0,2])
plt.ylim([0,2])
```

why do the regions overlap?  any advice for plotting the infinite regions?

[image]

---

The data points are just random numbers:

```
x.vertices

array([[ 0.59851675,  0.15271572],
       [ 0.24473753,  0.70398382],
       [ 0.10135325,  0.34601724],
       [ 0.42672008,  0.26129443],
       [ 0.54966835,  1.64315275],
       [ 0.24770706,  0.70543002],
       [ 0.39509645,  0.64211128],
       [ 0.63353948,  0.86992423],
       [ 0.57476256,  1.4533911 ],
       [ 0.76421296,  0.6054079 ],
       [ 0.9564816 ,  0.79492684],
       [ 0.94432943,  0.62496293]])
```

the regions are listed by number

```
x.regions

[[],
 [2, -1, 1],
 [3, 0, -1, 2],
 [5, 1, -1, 4],
 [6, 3, 2, 1, 5],
 [11, 9, 7, 8, 10],
 [8, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [9, 0, 3, 6, 7],
 [10, -1, 4, 8],
 [11, -1, 0, 9],
 [11, -1, 10]]
```

and from this we can re-construct the plot.  My question is what does the `-1` mean?

Answer (score 5):

[`scipy.spatial.Voronoi`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) uses the Qhull library underneath. In my experience Qhull contains several usability bugs. You hit [one of them](http://www.qhull.org/html/qvoronoi.htm#outputs):

> ### qvoronoi outputs
>
> #### Voronoi vertices
>
> [...]
>
> `FN`: list the Voronoi vertices for each Voronoi region. The first line
>   is the number of Voronoi regions. Each remaining line starts with the
>   number of Voronoi vertices. **Negative indices (e.g., -1) indicate
>   vertices outside of the Voronoi diagram.**

---

---

> why do the regions overlap?

So, `-1` in the first Voronoi region `[2, -1, 1]` from `x.regions` stands for *a vertex-at-infinity* (*that is not represented in* `x.vertices`). Yet, when you access `x.vertices` with that spurious index, you get the last vertex. This happens for every `-1` in your `x.regions` (note that those -1's denote different vertices-at-infinity). As a result you get spurious Voronoi edges connecting to the last vertex from `x.vertices`.

> any advice for plotting the infinite regions?

Why don't you simply use [`scipy.spatial.voronoi_plot_2d()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.voronoi_plot_2d.html)?

Comment: i don't just want the plot, i need the polygons that are computed. both finite polygons and infinite polygons. `-1` seems to stand for something different for each polygon

Comment: @johnmangual [cgal](https://www.cgal.org/) may have a better solution.  I was having some trouble getting it to compile, but there are lots of sources to help with installation

Comment: also @johnmangual Leon's answer is correct; the -1 just stands for portions of the Voronoi diagram that are "out of bounds."  It may help to think about a single point, and what its Voronoi diagram would look like; all points that could exist anywhere would be "closest" to the single point, so there would be no edges.  For 2 points, the Voronoi diagram would be a single plane that continued to infinity in all directions, etc.